# How can I get the new object id generated by DB sequence?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, oracle, entity-framework

I have table with sequence and trigger so it creates new id when inserting it to the DB.

How can I get the new object id, before calling SaveChanges()?

I need this id for the links between the new object and other objects.

I want to do it before calling SaveChanges because I want to have the option to rollback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get it without calling `SaveChanges()`. Think about it. The ID comes from the DB. `SaveChanges()` is the first thing which causes communication with the DB.

If you want to undo, you have several choices:

- In many cases, you don't need to know the ID client-side when inserting. Simply creating the relationship is enough.
- Use a client-generateable ID like a GUID.
- Use `TransactionScope` for a "real" DB transaction.
- Do an undo (`DeleteObject`) instead of a rollback.