# entity framework - how to find the id after submitting the entry

Tags: entity-framework, commit

the existing code is:

```
....
domainModel.EntityDataContext.Attach(entry);
....
domainModel.EntityDataContext.Commit();
```

I'm not allowed to edit the attach method and commit as it will create huge regression issues, but I'm wondering how can I obtain entry's id ?

Comment: Does the Id not automatically update on the entity after it is committed? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3290209/1341477 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5212787/1341477

Comment: This is not doable unless you are manually setting the id in your database.If you don't insert the key's value hasn't been generated yet.

Comment: You will need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893141/how-do-you-get-a-dbentityentry-entitykey-object-with-unknown-name

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Id of inserted entity in Entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @DaveWilliams the thing is I　cannot change the commit codes, so I cannot use the SaveChange etc. ..

Comment: If commit is not using SaveChanges then how is it saving data? If you really can't do anything to edit it then you may have to resort to fetching the data back from the database manually which seems a bit like a waste if using the framework.